# gdb - thread log

Tags: gdb

While I trying to debug a 'C' program with gdb, I always get the following continuously on the gdb console.

[Thread 0xb7fe4b70 (LWP 30576) exited]
[New Thread 0xb7fe4b70 (LWP 30577)]
[Thread 0xb7fe4b70 (LWP 30577) exited]
[New Thread 0xb7fe4b70 (LWP 30578)]
[Thread 0xb7fe4b70 (LWP 30578) exited]

Is there any reason why this is printed? And anyway to block this?

note: the program makes use of timers. Is that a possible cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set print thread-events off